# Q:Get rows count by indexPath of tableView comes `Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at:` error

Tags: ios, uitableview, rows, exc-bad-access, sections

In my tableView delegate methods:

I get `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` in my `tableView` `delegate` methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  ,
```

but in the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, I tried this method:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", section];
```

In this line , it shows the error:Thread 1：EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x)
and I taken the `(lldb)`:

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", section]
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7fff50739eb0.
```

If I don't get `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` in my `tableView` `delegate` methods:
      the error will not appear.

The below is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && numberOfRows != 1) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }



    return cell;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

        NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && numberOfRows != 1) {

             return 40;
        }else {
            return 5;
        }

    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)section];

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", section];  // this line shows the error.


    BOOL folded = [[_foldInfoDic objectForKey:key] boolValue];

    if (section == 0) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else {
        return folded?_arr.count:0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a error caused by this code:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", section];
```

Your code is run in an endless loop and end by the system. Look at the below:
[image]

When you call:

```
 NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
 NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];
```

in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, this will case an endless loop.

For Example(call either of them will cause an endless loop):

```
- (void)func1 {
    // Code
    [self func2];
}
- (void)func2 {
    // Code
    [self func1];
}
```

The Simplest solution is implement you code as below:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && numberOfRows != 1) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }



    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && numberOfRows != 1) {

        return 40;
    }else {
        return 5;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)section];

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", section];  // this line shows the error.


    BOOL folded = [[_foldInfoDic objectForKey:key] boolValue];

    if (section == 0) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return folded?_arr.count:1;
    } else {
        return folded?_arr.count:0;
    }
}
```